# Как заносить данные в базу данных, а после извлекать их из неё?

Tags: java, android, база-данных

Пишу приложение "Записи". Главная активность приложения выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на клавишу "Новая запись" осуществляется переход на эту активность (в этой активности создаётся и сохраняется запись): 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В ней производятся ввод и сохранение данных, данные должны сохранятся в базу данных в виде текста (в том числе и достаточно длинного текста, вроде параграфа из книги), затем, при нажатии на клавишу "Все записи" в главной активности, можно получить доступ к списку из этих записей и открыть любую из них. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать
P.S. Не работал раньше с базами данных, поэтому слабо представляю даже то, как это гуглить

Код активности для добавления записи:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bottomSave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_below="@id/bottomSave"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="Введите запись"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Код активности, в которой должен быть список записей (я использовал элемент ListView, но не уверен, что это правильно):

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="729dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

скрин этой активности не прикрепляю, так как пока что она выглядит как пустое окно

Comment: << слабо представляю даже то, как это гуглить>> Ключевики: android, SQLite, базы данных. Сразу найдёте горы материалов. Например, эту чудесную статью:http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/sqlite/android-sqlite.php.

Comment: Посмотри в сторону Room

Comment: И да сейчас  используют RecyclerView, а не  ListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам давно работал с SQLite, но у меня есть одно приложение с ним, которое раньше делал. Не могу гарантировать, что этот код полностью будет работать, но Вы поймете суть работы с ним.

1. В этом коде ничего сложного нет. Просто создаете БД.

   `public class CartDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {`

   ```
   public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Cart.db";
   public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

   public CartDatabase(Context context) {
       super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
       final String CreateCartTable = "CREATE TABLE " +
               CartInfoDatabase.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
               CartInfoDatabase._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
               CartInfoDatabase.COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
               CartInfoDatabase.COLUMN_AMOUNT + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
               CartInfoDatabase.COLUMN_IMAGEID + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
               CartInfoDatabase.COLUMN_PRICE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
               CartInfoDatabase.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" +
               ");";

       db.execSQL(CreateCartTable);
   }

   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
       db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CartInfo.CartInfoDatabase.TABLE_NAME);
       onCreate(db);
   }
   ```

   `}`
2. Это вспомогательный класс к классу выше.

   `public class CartInfo {`

   ```
   private CartInfo(){

   }

   public static final class CartInfoDatabase implements BaseColumns{
       public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Cart";
       public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "Name";
       public static final String COLUMN_AMOUNT = "Amount";
       public static final String COLUMN_IMAGEID = "ImageId";
       public static final String COLUMN_PRICE = "Price";
       public static final String COLUMN_TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";
   }
   ```

   `}`
3. Чтобы добавить новые данные надо создать переменную и дать ей права на запись данных.

`private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;`

`CartDatabase cartDatabase = new CartDatabase(context);`

`sqLiteDatabase = cartDatabase.getWritableDatabase();`

После этого создать переменную ContentValues и записать в неё все данные, которые надо добавить в БД и подтвердить.

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    contentValues.put(CartInfo.CartInfoDatabase.COLUMN_NAME, pizzaNameInDialog.getText().toString());
                    contentValues.put(CartInfo.CartInfoDatabase.COLUMN_AMOUNT, pizzaOnePrice.getText().toString());
                    contentValues.put(CartInfo.CartInfoDatabase.COLUMN_IMAGEID, image);
                    contentValues.put(CartInfo.CartInfoDatabase.COLUMN_PRICE, fullPrice.getText().toString());

                    sqLiteDatabase.insert(CartInfo.CartInfoDatabase.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
```

4. Адаптер. Ставите курсор в 0 позицию и проходите по всему списку.

`public class AdapterForCart extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterForCart.GroceryViewHolder>{`

```
private Context adapterContext;
private Cursor adapterCursor;

public AdapterForCart(Context context, Cursor cursor){
    this.adapterContext = context;
    this.adapterCursor = cursor;
}

public class GroceryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView nameText;
    public TextView countText;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextView priceText;

    public GroceryViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        nameText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_cartinfo_name);
        countText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_cartinfo_amount);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_cartinfo_imageview);
        priceText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_cartinfo_price);
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public GroceryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(adapterContext);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cartinfo_item, viewGroup, false);
    return new GroceryViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GroceryViewHolder groceryViewHolder, int i) {

    if (!adapterCursor.moveToPosition(i)){
        return;
    }

    String name = adapterCursor.getString(adapterCursor.getColumnIndex(CartInfo.CartInfoDatabase.COLUMN_NAME));
    int amount = adapterCursor.getInt(adapterCursor.getColumnIndex(CartInfo.CartInfoDatabase.COLUMN_AMOUNT));
    long id = adapterCursor.getLong(adapterCursor.getColumnIndex(CartInfo.CartInfoDatabase._ID));
    String ImageId = adapterCursor.getString(adapterCursor.getColumnIndex(CartInfo.CartInfoDatabase.COLUMN_IMAGEID));
    String fullPizzaOnePrice = adapterCursor.getString(adapterCursor.getColumnIndex(CartInfo.CartInfoDatabase.COLUMN_PRICE));

    groceryViewHolder.nameText.setText(name);
    groceryViewHolder.countText.setText(String.valueOf(amount));
    groceryViewHolder.itemView.setTag(id);

    Picasso.get().load(ImageId).into(groceryViewHolder.imageView);

    groceryViewHolder.priceText.setText(fullPizzaOnePrice);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return adapterCursor.getCount();
}

public void swapCursor(Cursor newCursor){
    if (adapterCursor != null){
        adapterCursor.close();
    }

    adapterCursor = newCursor;

    if (newCursor != null){
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

`}`

5. Вывод данных. Также, создать переменную, дать ей права на запись и сделать вывод в RecyclerView или во что Вы хотите. Еще надо переопределить метод, который делает запрос всех данных к БД. (getAllItems) Для удаления также добавил метод. Если что, строка `CartInfo.CartInfoDatabase.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DESC "` сортирует данные.

   `private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;`

   `private AdapterForCart adapterForCart;`

   `CartDatabase cartDatabase = new CartDatabase(getActivity());`

`sqLiteDatabase = cartDatabase.getWritableDatabase();`

```
    RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    adapterForCart = new AdapterForCart(getActivity(), getAllItems());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterForCart);

private void removeItem(long id) {
    sqLiteDatabase.delete(CartInfo.CartInfoDatabase.TABLE_NAME,
            CartInfo.CartInfoDatabase._ID + "=" + id, null);
    adapterForCart.swapCursor(getAllItems());
}

private Cursor getAllItems(){
    return  sqLiteDatabase.query(CartInfo.CartInfoDatabase.TABLE_NAME,
            null, null, null, null, null,
            CartInfo.CartInfoDatabase.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DESC ");
}
```

Надеюсь, более-менее обьяснил картину. Советую посмотреть несколько видео по этой теме.