# Как в Android Studio выводить данные из базы данных в отдельную активность?

Tags: java, android, база-данных, android-studio, sqlite

Пишу что-то вроде текстового редактора, у меня есть база данных, информация в которую заносится через текстовое поле EditText, необходимо сделать так, чтобы сохранённые записи из базы данных (которые могут состоять из достаточно большого текста) отображались в виде списка имён (под которыми сохраняются тексты), чтобы после нажатия на одно из имён открывалась новая активность с текстом, которому принадлежит это имя
Код базы данных:

```
package com.example.posts;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactDb";
    public static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_TEXT = "text";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "(" + KEY_ID
                + " integer primary key," + KEY_NAME + " text," + KEY_TEXT + " text" + ")");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

        onCreate(db);

    }
}
```

Код активности:

```
package com.example.posts;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class NewEntry extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    Button btnAdd, btnRead, btnClear;
    EditText etName, etText;

    DBHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_entry);

        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnRead = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRead);
        btnRead.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDell);
        btnClear.setOnClickListener(this);

        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        etText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String name = etName.getText().toString();
        String text = etText.getText().toString();

        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();


        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.buttonSave:
                contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_NAME, name);
                contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_TEXT, text);

                database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, contentValues);
                break;

            case R.id.btnRead:
                Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, null, null, null, null, null);

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_ID);
                    int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_NAME);
                    int emailIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_TEXT);
                    do {
                        Log.d("mLog", "ID = " + cursor.getInt(idIndex) +
                                ", name = " + cursor.getString(nameIndex) +
                                ", email = " + cursor.getString(emailIndex));
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                } else
                    Log.d("mLog","0 rows");

                cursor.close();
                break;

            case R.id.btnDell:
                database.delete(DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, null);
                break;
        }
        dbHelper.close();
    }
}
```

Код xml файла для ввода данных:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonSave"
        android:text="@string/read"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDell"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnRead"
        android:text="удалить"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnDell"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Введите название записи"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="Введите запись"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Код xml файла для вывода списка имён (не уверен, что в этом файле хоть что-то правильно):

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_num"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Код активности, в которой будет выводится список имён:

```
package com.example.posts;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class postsList extends Activity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_posts_list);
    }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне сделать из базы данных sqlite список имён для доступа к информации, которая хранится в этих данных и как вывести текст из конкретной ячейки под конкретным именем в отдельную активность

Comment: Недавно был подобный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1044806

Comment: @ Andrey Mihalev, спасибо за ссылку, но это не совсем то, мне нужно, чтобы создавалось что-то вроде списка кнопок, каждая из которых открывает конкретный текст из базы данных (в которой этих текстов много), так как содержимое базы данных может как увеличиваться, так и уменьшаться, то "список из кнопок" также может становиться больше или меньше

Comment: Какая разница что вы хотите выводить, текст, кнопку, картинку. Пример адаптера для RV там есть. Начните уже пробовать писать адаптер, а после задавать вопрос о том, что не получается. Пока я вижу в вопросе одну воду, даже суть вопроса не понимаю.

Comment: Можете использовать Firebase, если не критично важна локальная бд. Реализация Firebase DB легче воспринимается, чем Sqlite.