# Не получается передать данные из sqlite в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqlite, recyclerview

Есть база данных, в которой 3 столбца: id, имя, текст:

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

    public class DBHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactDb";
        public static final String TABLE_TEXT = "text";

        public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
        public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
        public static final String KEY_TEXT = "text";

        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_TEXT + "(" + KEY_ID
                    + " integer primary key," + KEY_NAME + " text," + KEY_TEXT + " text" + ")");

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_TEXT);

            onCreate(db);


   }
}
```

Информация в БД поступает из 2 полей ввода текста:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonSave"
        android:text="@string/read"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDell"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnRead"
        android:text="удалить"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnDell"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Введите название записи"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="Введите запись"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Я пытаюсь передать содержимое БД в элемент RecyclerView:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_num"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</FrameLayout>
```

(руководствуясь документацией android https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)

И возникают следующие проблемы (в комментариях к коду ):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class postsList extends Activity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_posts_list);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_num);


        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset); //Я не знаю, что передавать сюда
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

Адаптер (в адаптере проблема тоже в комментарии):

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private String[] mDataset;


    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView textView;
        public MyViewHolder(TextView v) {
            super(v);
            textView = v;
        }
    }

    public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset) { //Я не понимаю, откуда берётся этот массив, что с ним делать и для чего он нужен
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                     int viewType) {

        TextView v = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.activity_new_entry, parent, false);

        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.textView.setText(mDataset[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

И не знаю, правильно ли я строю адаптер, ибо у меня 2 поля ввода, а в списке должно отображаться имя текста (элемент базы данных name), чтобы можно было потом, щёлкнув на это имя, открыть текст
    Подскажите, пожалуйста, что мне с этим делать
    Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Здравствуйте. Посмотрите сюда, возможно немного поможет. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1044806/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%91/1044846#1044846

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае лучше использовать не массив строк а массив объектов. Создайте новый файл с классом:

```
public class TextRow{
    public Integer id;
    public String name;
    public String text;
    public TextRow(Integer id, String name, String text){
        this.id = id;
        this.name= name;
        this.text= text;
    }
}
```

Допишите в `Activity`:

```
private DataBaseHelper mDataBaseHelper;
//...

if(this.mDataBaseHelper == null){
    this.mDataBaseHelper = new DBHelper(this);
}
SQLiteDatabase db = mDataBaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
String sql = "select name, text from text";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{});
List<TextRow> myDataset = new ArrayList<>();
if (c != null) {
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            int idId= c.getColumnIndex("_id");
            int idName= c.getColumnIndex("name");
            int idText= c.getColumnIndex("text");
            myDataset.add(new TextRow(c.getInt(idId),c.getString(idName),c.getString(idText)));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
}

mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset); //Я не знаю, что передавать сюда
```

Исправьте в `MyAdapter`:

```
private List<TextRow> mDataset;
//...
public MyAdapter(List<TextRow> myDataset) { //Я не понимаю, откуда берётся этот массив, что с ним делать и для чего он нужен
    mDataset = myDataset;
}
//...
holder.textView.setText(mDataset[position].name);
//...
```

Если таблица не пустая то строки должны появиться в списке. Если пустая то добавить можно так:

```
if(this.mDataBaseHelper == null){
    this.mDataBaseHelper = new DBHelper(this);
}
SQLiteDatabase db = mDataBaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
db.execSQL("insert into text (_id,name,text)values(1,'MyFirstName','MyFirstText')");
```

Comment: Возникли небольшие проблемы в активности, в строке SQLiteDatabase db = DBHelper.getReadableDatabase(); подчёркивает getReadableDatabase красным

Comment: Закрывающая скобка цикла do тоже подчёркнута красным, подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так

Comment: И я до конца не понял, где должна быть закрывающая скобка if (c != null), подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: Добавил как создать mDataBaseHelper. Исправил цикл.

Comment: Возникла ещё небольшая проблема, как я понял, последний элемента написанного Вами кода (который начинается со строки if(this.mDataBaseHelper == null){ ) нужно вставлять в Activity, Я добавил его в конце метода onCreate и было подчёркнуто красным слово inset и выделено красным слово commit. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что с этим делать

Comment: Извините, `insert` конечно же.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать с commit, он до сих пор выделен красным (в строке db.commit())

Comment: Он не нужен, должно вставиться и так.

Comment: В коде ошибок больше не возникает, но во время работы приложения, когда я пытаюсь перейти на активность со списком, приложение вылетает и появляется следующая ошибка:
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.posts, PID: 2548
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.posts/com.example.posts.postsList}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase com.example.posts.DBHelper.getReadableDatabase()' on a null object reference

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101171/discussion-between-semenov-nilolay-and--says-reinstate-monica).

Comment: вот, пожалуйста: https://github.com/Nikolui333/Posts